# How to name UI components accurately?

Tags: user-interface, naming-conventions

I'm trying to find an accurate name for the following component but realize I have no idea what to call it.

It is composed of a title (optional), a value displayed in the center, and two buttons to increase/decrease the value.
It could be `CountSelector`, `HorizontalCounter`, I don't know...

[image]

For me an accurate name would be:

- one that carries meaning and immediatly describes what the component is (without having to look at the code, or even see the component rendered)
- one the is searchable and fairly standard (eg. if I search "Breadcrumb" I will immediately find examples and any designer or FE engineer will know what I'm talking about)

Naming is super important but I find that quite often I have no idea how to define a UI component I am building, so the second part to my question is: **What are some good resources that list all kinds of components and can be used as an example/reference for naming?**

Answer (score 0):

I would use the name *steppableIntegerField*, *steppableNumericField*, or maybe just *steppableField*.

Here is the strategy which leads to the choice. When you need to come up with a name it's a good practice to first find a noun which describes the thing or concept in the most general sense. In this case it's an input *field*. This will be the last word in the identifier. Then you try to find attribute words which describe the thing with sufficient precision in the context where the identifier is used. In this case an integer or maybe a decimal number is expected so *integerField* or *numericField* is a good choice. What is characteristic of your input field is also that it has increment and decrement step buttons, so therefor we can also add the word *steppable* to distinguish it from other input fields without these buttons.